# Geting Keyerror even though the Key is present in Dict?

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, nlp, sentiment-analysis

I am trying to find the word vector NLP sentiment analysis for review analysis, I am getting key error for , but the key is present in the dictionary, I dont why Am getting this error

````
txt_fname = 'C:\\Users\\arune\\Desktop\\sentiment labelled sentences\\amazon_cells_labelled.txt'
df = pd.read_table(txt_fname,names=['sentence','sentiment'])

df['tokenized'] = df['sentence'].apply(lambda a: word_tokenize(a))


```
vocab = set()
for tokens in df['tokenized']:
    for a in tokens:
        vocab.add(a)
        
len(vocab)
```

vocab = {a:b for a,b in enumerate(sorted(vocab))}
vocab   

rand_wv = np.random.rand(len(vocab),300)
rand_wv.shape

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
train, test = train_test_split(df, test_size=0.2,random_state=42)
````

```
X_train = []
for tok_sent in train['tokenized']:
    doc_vec = np.zeros(300)
    for t in tok_sent:
        word_index = vocab[t]
        word_vec = rand_wv[word_index]
        doc_vec += word_vec
    doc_vec = doc_vec/len(tok_sent)
    X_train.append(doc_vec)
    
X_train = np.array(X_train)
y_train = train['sentiment']
X_train.shape
```

Getting error as :

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-64-add70741d289> in <module>
      3     doc_vec = np.zeros(300)
      4     for t in tok_sent:
----> 5         word_index = vocab[t]
      6         word_vec = rand_wv[word_index]
      7         doc_vec += word_vec

KeyError: 'does'
```

Comment: Your `vocab` was created from `enumerate`, so its keys are the integers starting with 0.  The words are its values.  I think you want `vocab = {b:a for a,b ...}` so the words are keys.

Answer (score 0):

As Tim Roberts has answered in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74663637/geting-keyerror-even-though-the-key-is-present-in-dict#comment131785787_74663637):

> Your `vocab` was created from `enumerate`, so its keys are the integers starting with 0.

As also suggested, you should create your vocab like so:

```py
vocab = {w: id_ for id_, w in enumerate(sorted(vocab))}
```